# Check app in device is latest version or not latest version by code android

Tags: android, version, updates

At the moment,I have an android project and it is using google text to speech to speack japanese.
But japanese is only support at latest of google text to speech while google text to speech in my device is not latest version.
I want to check google text to speech is latest version or not latest.
If not latest,go to page google text to speech in google play store to update.
How must I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the PackageManager? For example:

```
PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
try {
   PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo("android.speech.tts", 0); // use the exact name!
   String packageName = info.packageName;
   int versionCode = info.versionCode;
   String versionName = info.versionName;
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   }
```